# Printer reports "printer killed" and "homing failed", what does that mean?

Tags: creality-ender-3

My Ender 3 v2 is reporting `printer killed` and `homing failed`.

Does that means that my printer is dead?

Note that I just got the printer 3 days ago and I haven't been able to do any prints.

Comment: This question doesn't provide enough context to get answers that may help you out. Please describe in detail what you are doing, which steps you have done, what file you are printing, how you obtained it. Do the axes run free when the steppers are not powered, did you check all the cables? There is a lot more you can do to troubleshoot some basics first. Do the steppers run at all, etc.? We'd love to help! But with this amount of information we need to guess. A valid question is how to troubleshoot this, please [edit] the question else this question might be closed for the lack of information.

Comment: As stated, please [edit] your question and add more info (don't add info in this comment section). Has the printer always stated these messages for the whole three days, since the moment it came out of the box? If not, and it worked initially for a while, what happened immediately before the messages appeared...? This might give a clue as to why the messages appeared in the first place. Can you communicate with the board via USB from a PC? Photos of the messages might help. What happens at power up - any motor noises, etc.?

Comment: This might help you provide more detail: [Helpful Templates / Help us help you!](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/395/4762)

Comment: Have you reviewed the assembly instructions, step by step, looking for something you might have missed?   Was the printer new to you or used ?

Comment: What is the last motion that it does before reporting this error?  Where does the error appear - on the printer's internal display or somewhere else?   It could be a video of the startup process would be informative.

Comment: Sounds like limit switches might be mis-calibrated.

Comment: your printer gained life and had to be killed as it posed a threat... joking aside, printer may have a power (motors, and not just power supply), limit switch, or other issue that prevented homing.  try jogging without homing among other things like manually triggering potentially inverted limits) just to get an idea of what is operational.  Be prepared to use a multimeter to debug after.